# Horizontal offset on second monitor over VGA only (osX)

Tags: macos, vga, external-display

Im running osX 10.7.4 on a macbook pro and for some reason my second monitor is playing up. If I connect via VGA I have a horizontal offset of about 200px (more than I can manually adjust for in my monitor settings), this has been working fine for about a year until now - restarts and so on do not make a difference. If I instead connect to the same monitor via HDMI everything is fine. Any idea why this may be / how I can change the horizontal offset at the os level?

Thanks